# Django + jquery : getting 301

Tags: jquery, django

I have tabs that calls via javascript urls of django to complete the "container"

But i am getting 301, any idea why this is happening?

Server misconfiguration?

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
     (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
     (r'^list/', 'carsproj.cars.views.list'),
)
```

view

```
def list(request):
if request.is_ajax():
    return render_to_response('templates/generic_list.html',
                          { 'items' : Cars.objects.all(), 'name' : 'List - Cars' },
                          context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

javascript

```
the_tabs.click(function(e){

    var element = $(this);

    if(element.find('#overLine').length) return false;

    var bg = element.attr('class').replace('tab ','');

    $('#overLine').remove();

    $('<div>',{
        id:'overLine',
        css:{
            display:'none',
            width:element.outerWidth()-2,
            background:topLineColor[bg] || 'white'
        }}).appendTo(element).fadeIn('slow');


    if(!element.data('cache'))
    {   
        $('#contentHolder').html('<img src="/media/img/ajax_preloader.gif" width="64" height="64" class="preloader" />');

        $.get(element.data('page'),function(msg){
            $('#contentHolder').html(msg);

            element.data('cache',msg);
        });
    }
    else $('#contentHolder').html(element.data('cache'));

    e.preventDefault();
})
```

Please tell me what more information you need, js code? template? url.py? I WILL EDIT THIS POST FOR ADD MORE DATA

Comment: JS, url.py and the view code would be a good start I guess...

Comment: Where is it redirecting you to?

Comment: it is redirecting to the link os the tab.
for example host/list/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was adsense code!!
remove the adsense from the ajax response and now its workign!

Answer (score 0):

An HTTP 301 is a redirect.  Without seeing the actual output, I'd guess you might need to authenticate first.

Comment: do you think that jquery .get is doing that?
I know what is 301, but dont know why is happening

Comment: I highly doubt it.  Something is sending you a redirect, and you need to figure out what/why.